# Eclipse & Xtext - DSL Editor not working on deployment

Tags: java, deployment, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, xtext

I've implemented a DSL using the Xtext framework on the Eclipse IDE. Additionally, I've created several UI features (Import/Export handlers, for example) that are available when I run my Eclipse Application.

Now I'm trying to deploy my application as a standalone product. I created a ".product" file in the ".ide" package of my project and everything works when I run my application from that ".product" file.

However, when I DO deploy it, I run the generated ".exe" file and the editor fails when I create a ".mydsl" file (I don't even get the prompt to convert the project to an Xtext project). The error is:

```
Failed to create injector for org.xtext.myDsl.Mydsl ExtensionFactory: org.xtext.myDsl.Mydsl.MydslExecutableExtensionFactory
```

I'm totally clueless with this, as I don't believe I'm missing any plugin imports... what could I be missing?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This might help you https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/489049/. You probably don't have all the needed classes/resources on your classpath.

Comment: make sure you dont have any warnings on any build.properties files

Comment: I'm not sure which one did it, but I applied both of your suggestions and, lo and behold, it works! Thanks a lot! Cheers. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kind of issues is ususally caused by some inconsistencies in your eclipse metadata in `build.properties`. Make sure all source folders and resources like the manifest and the plugin.xml are listed there. You should get a warning in eclipse like

[image: Screenshot of warning in eclipse]

There is a quickfix for the issue as well.

Comment: Done deal, that fixed it! Can't thank you enough! Cheers!